# Создание слайдера на HTML, CSS, JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, анимация, slider

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать на HTML, CSS, JS такой слайдер как на этой странице https://www.superlist.com/. Чтобы когда видео заканчиволось, начиналось новое и следущий заголовок менял цвет, а также чтобы можно было нажимать на заголовки и принадлежащие им видео проигрывались.Заранее спасибо!)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Там не видео заканчивается, а каждые 7 или 8 секунд просто автоматически перелистывается слайдер.

Comment: такую штуку легко сделать при помощи slick-slider и его метода asNavFor, либо же swiper-slider, но я пользуюсь slick, поэтому про swiper ничего сказать не могу. А видео нужно будет вставить убрав все controls и включить autoplay.

Comment: Но если вы решили конечно свой слайдер написать на чистом js, то флаг вам в руки)).